# How do I test this very old legacy Javascript module without rewriting it?

Tags: javascript, testing, require

How do I load and instantiate this legacy javascript module for testing, without modifying it?

The legacy module (`foo.js`):

```
var Smurf = {};

Smurf.Foo = function() {};
Smurf.Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function() {
        return 'baz';
    }
};
```

The legacy front-end (working):

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var foo = new Smurf.Foo();
    var qux = foo.bar();
});
</script>
```

The new test (failing):

```
const something = require('foo.js');
var foo = new Smurf.Foo();
```

Result:

```
Error: Failed to load file test/test.js
ReferenceError: Smurf is not defined
```

Comment: How do you normally load `foo.js`?

Comment: like this in a web page: `<script src="foo.js"></script>` (answer updated)

Comment: Focus on the first error "Error: Failed to load file test/test.js", you shouldn't need rewrite anything just make sure that the code is in the right place on disk.

Comment: @WillSheppard If that is not a module, you cannot `require` it. It probably sets `window.Smurf` than exporting `Smurf` object. You can fetch the script as text string and use `eval` or `Function` to run its code.

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS, you can use the `vm` module https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vmruninthiscontextcode-options.

```js
const { runInThisContext } = require('vm');
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
function legacyRequire(path) { return runInThisContext(readFileSync(path)); }

var something = legacyRequire('./foo.js');
var foo = new Smurf.Foo();
console.assert(foo.bar() === 'baz');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is include both the file you need to test and the file with the tests in a new html file. This way, first the file that needs testing is loaded and everything it has in it can be tested in the test file.

`test.hml`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script scr="foo.js">
        <script src="test.js">
    </head>
</html>
```

Every time you need to run a test, open `test.html` in a browser. Of course you need to rewrite the test file so it shows some output, either in the `console` or in the html itself.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy *module* isn't a CommonJS module, therefore **require()** will not work. I recommend reading through this [post](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) to understand how require() works.

The short answer would be - you cannot "require()" foo.js and access **Smurf** unless the foo.js is exporting it (using something like module.exports).

Since you mentioned not wanting to rewrite the legacy code, I'd like to point you to this **neat trick** to [Import non-ESM libraries in ES Modules, with client-side vanilla JS](https://lea.verou.me/2020/07/import-non-esm-libraries-in-es-modules-with-client-side-vanilla-js/)